# Confused on how to include/compile a dependency in a makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have a program with this hierarchy:

```
-| base folder
- - main.c
- - Makefile
- -| motor control
- - - controller.c
- - - controller.h
- -| Build-Assets
- - - Makefile.Release
```

The point of this is to clean up `main.c`.

In `controller.c` I am basically adding another layer of abstraction to handle eventual errors and to hide all of the logic that handles driving straight etc.

I am wondering how I could write the makefile to first compile the motor control and then compile `main.c`.

This is the code I am using (and I honestly don't understand much of the second one, I took it from the 'getting started' page of the project I'm working on)

### Makefile

```
MAKEFILE_BASE = ./Build-Assets/Makefile

.PHONY: default clean release release-clean

default: release

clean: release-clean

release:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_BASE).Release

release-clean:
    $(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_BASE).Release clean
```

### Makefile.Release

```
TARGET = $(notdir $(shell pwd))

LIBS = -lm -lev3dev-c
D_BIN = Build-Assets

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
LIBS := $(LIBS) -lws2_32
D_BIN := $(D_BIN)/mingw
endif

D_H = ../../source/ev3
CFLAGS = $(addprefix -I, $(D_H)) -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wall -Wno-comment

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
CC = gcc
else
CC = arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
endif

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
E_BIN = .exe
else
E_BIN =
endif

F_BIN = $(TARGET)$(E_BIN)

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(D_BIN)/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c)))

.PHONY: default all clean

default: $(F_BIN)
all: default

$(OBJECTS): $(D_BIN)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(F_BIN) $(OBJECTS)

$(F_BIN): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -Wall $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f $(D_BIN)/*.o
    -rm -f $(F_BIN)
```

Comment: Is your code `controller.c` getting built?, I don't see it in your `Makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to modify the Makefile.

This line controls what .o files get made:

```
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(D_BIN)/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c)))
```

The `$(wildcard *.c)` portion matches all of the .c files in the top level directory. This will not match .c files in any other directory.

Change it to this:

```
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(D_BIN)/, $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c motor/*.c)))
```

(`motor` should be the name of your motor controller subdirectory.)

Note that if you have `motor/controller.c`, the Makefile will attempt to build this and put it in `Build-Assets/motor/controller.o`. For this to work, the directory `Build-Assets/motor` must **already exist**.